# Return variable value from request.get inside one function to another NODEJS express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am calling a function that request.gets some json and fills in the variables from my router.get

The variables get their value inside the callFunc function but they are undefined in my router.get

How do I make them global so that I can assign the value inside request.get and use the value in the router.get

```
var title;
var headline;

router.get('/test/code/:code', function(req, res, next){
var procedure = "EXECUTE procedureName 999, 'userName', "+req.params.code
callFunc(procedure)     

  res.render('display', { 
    title: title,           // <-- This value here is undefined
    descritpion: headline,  // <-- This value here is undefined
    var1: 'block sidebar',
    var2: 'block content',
    image: 'http://baidun.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/SI_RM_1070bw-900x598.jpg',
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZB_VPDXAhKU'

  })
})


function callFunc(procedure){
request.get('http://myWebservice.com/myService.asmx/myServiceDB?callback=&userName=username&procedureName='+procedure, function(req, res, body){

    var testValue = body.slice(1, -2);
    var result1 = JSON.parse(testValue);
    var result2 = JSON.parse(result1);
    title = result2.jobSelect[0].jobTitle;
    headline = decodeURI(result2.jobSelect[0].jobHeadline);
    console.log(title)     // <-- I get the right value here
    console.log(headline)  // <-- I get the right value here
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply way could be using res.render as a call back.

```
var title;
var headline;

router.get('/test/code/:code', function(req, res, next){
var procedure = "EXECUTE procedureName 999, 'userName', "+req.params.code
callFunc(procedure, function(title, headline) {     

  res.render('display', { 
    title: title,           
    descritpion: headline,
    var1: 'block sidebar',
    var2: 'block content',
    image: 'http://baidun.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/SI_RM_1070bw-900x598.jpg',
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZB_VPDXAhKU'

  })
})
})


function callFunc(procedure, cb){
request.get('http://myWebservice.com/myService.asmx/myServiceDB?callback=&userName=username&procedureName='+procedure, function(req, res, body){

    var testValue = body.slice(1, -2);
    var result1 = JSON.parse(testValue);
    var result2 = JSON.parse(result1);
    title = result2.jobSelect[0].jobTitle;
    headline = decodeURI(result2.jobSelect[0].jobHeadline);
    cb(title, headline);
})
}
```

Comment: This was the solution I used, thank you. The reason I chose this answer over the other is because it's a step simpler.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a need to globally scope that data. You could simply have callFunc with a callback, and pass a data object back.

```
router.get('/test/code/:code', function(req, res, next){
    var procedure = "EXECUTE procedureName 999, 'userName', "+req.params.code
    callFunc(procedure, function(obj) {     
        res.render('display', { 
            title: obj.title,           
            descritpion: obj.headline,
            var1: 'block sidebar',
            var2: 'block content',
            image: 'http://baidun.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/SI_RM_1070bw-900x598.jpg',
            url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZB_VPDXAhKU'
        });
    });
});

function callFunc(procedure, callback){
    request.get('http://myWebservice.com/myService.asmx/myServiceDB?callback=&userName=username&procedureName='+procedure, function(req, res, body){
        var testValue = body.slice(1, -2);
        var result1 = JSON.parse(testValue);
        var result2 = JSON.parse(result1);
        var obj = {
            title: result2.jobSelect[0].jobTitle,
            headline: decodeURI(result2.jobSelect[0].jobHeadline)
        };
        callback(obj);
    })
}
```